# Libre Office Calc Formula to Calculate a Percentage of a Value in any given cell

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

SO, I'm trying to find a formula that will take the value of a given cell (X) and add a percentage (+ Z%) and give me the result as X is expected to change weekly.

Example: Cell A1 contents are $1.50. In Cell A2 I want to display the SUM value of A1 which is $1.50 plus 15%. Which should be $1.725. I have tried multiple formulas and the only one that I can think of that makes sense would be "=A1+15% but that only adds 0.15 to the value of A1.

Any ideas?

Comment: only use `=A1*1.15` if you multiplicate the value by 1 you got the 100% or the current value and the .15 is the 15 percent expressed in decimal.

Comment: you're welcome, I'm going to put this as an answer to let you close the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only use `=A1*1.15` if you multiplicate the value by 1 you got the 100% or the current value and the .15 is the 15 percent expressed in decimal